# how to know what is the module used in specific section in admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

when i want to override a frontend module , it is so easy, if there is a module that i dont know where it comes from , i can simply enable template hint , but my problem is when i want to change or adding something in admin panel , there's not template hint , and i cant know where anything is coming from and sometimes it is a xml file not phtml like the frontend , how can i know them

for example i need to add a new input in table rates section but i dont know where is displaying form [image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing, You can enable template path hint for admin as well

[image]

But In your case template path hint will not help much.

All System configuration file can be found at `{Vendor}/{module}/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` e.g. `/vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

just create new system.xml in your module and add following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="tablerate" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="900" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="test" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Test</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: it worked, look i have a custom module named Main/Store and inside there is Block folder , i created Main/Store/Block/Adminhtml/State_creator.php class , and i gave the field the block class like this type="Main/Store/Block/Adminhtml/State_creator" but i got 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Main\Store\Block\Adminhtml\State_creator does not exist , this is my code too , there is no problem with name class, name space..

Comment: this is my code      `<?php

namespace Main\Store\Block\Adminhtml;

class State_creator extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        // $this->setType('file');
    }     
}
`

Comment: it is type="Main\Store\Block\Adminhtml\State_creator" not type="Main/Store/Block/Adminhtml/State_creator" but the same error